# Creating the pie chart according to the dataframe

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How to create a pie chart of the death, confirmed and recovered fields in this data set by region.

Comment: Try [this guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_pie_charts.htm)

Comment: i am trying. I asked for help because I couldn't tear apart the data set. Nobody helps, everyone says try. I couldn't ask for help if I could do it myself.

Comment: Here, you'll help on the problems you are facing with the coding. Your question is broad. and the data set has many dimensions on which the pie chart could be made. When you are asking for help, you need to show what you have tried and where you are facing the problem. If you want to know how to extract information from the dataset to plot the pie chart, the question can be posted at stats.stackexchange.com. Anyway, I have added my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perfect for a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(region, confirmed, recovered, death) %>% 
  gather(type, value, -region) %>% 
  group_by(region,type) %>%
  summarise(value= sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", value, fill =region)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill(), color="white") + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = region), direction = "y",
                           position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_discrete("") +
  facet_wrap(~type) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

For labels I used function `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel` package to easily avoid overplotting.